# Angular material stepper with next button in header

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im trying to modify mat stepper with a next button along with the headers of the stepper.MY current steps look like:

```
  <mat-step  label="Details" state="details" fxFlex="100" [stepControl]="secondForm">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepTwo"></ng-container>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step  label="Options" state="options" fxFlex="100" [stepControl]="thirdForm">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepThree"></ng-container>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Review" state="review" fxFlex="100"  editable="false">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepFour"></ng-container>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step >
      <ng-template matStepLabel>
          <p (click)="stepChange()"><mat-icon >{{nextIndexIcon}}</mat-icon>{{nextIndexName}}<mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>Step {{stepnumber}}
          of 5</p>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepFive"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
```

The fourth step is modified to behave like a next step button as above. It is working as intended (almost) ..Now the problem is that,my second from last step does not have a form and does not have any validations. I want to make it mandatory for the user to view this step eventhough it doesn't have any forms. Currently it is skipping this step and moving to final step.

Comment: isn't it possible to just have an empty form to bypass it?

Comment: I created empty form with a check field,but when to i check this to true?

Comment: Setting the stepper in linear mode should make every step mandatory, even without a stepControl

Comment: not in my case,the last step is used as a next button

Comment: Linear mode doesnt work without step COntrol

Comment: You may bind to the `completed` property of mat-step: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStep